# Is there a way to save input information after the program terminates?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I'm a little new to java, having just started a high-school level class in August. I am still learning the basic information, and have a general understanding of the basics, such as JOptionPane, Scanner, Array and system lines. My question is if there is a way to create a standalone Java program, where you can just double click an icon on the desktop to launch it. If so, is there a way to create a file dump where you can only access it by a password? I already have a basic login program that allows access based on a predetermined user and password. The goal of this program is to create a secure (even though it's basic) file share between people who are meant to have it and keep out those who aren't, that contains specific files (.docx, .jpeg, .pptx, etc.) that are utilized for school work. If so, is there also a way to limit access to these files to being only accessed through this program?

This is the code I have so far:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane.*;
import java.lang.Math.*;
import java.lang.System.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class UserLog extends JFrame  

{

public static void main(String[]Args) throws InterruptedException 
    {
    boolean isValid=false;
    while(!isValid)
        {
    // Components related to "login" field    
    JLabel label_loginname = new JLabel("Enter your login name:");    
    JTextField loginname = new JTextField(15);    
    // loginname.setText("EnterLoginNameHere"); 
    // Pre-set some text    
    // Components related to "password" field    
    JLabel label_password = new JLabel("Enter your password:");    
    JPasswordField password = new JPasswordField();    
    // password.setEchoChar('@'); 
    // Sets @ as masking character    
    // password.setEchoChar('\000'); 
    // Turns off masking    
    JCheckBox rememberCB = new JCheckBox("Remember me");

    Object[] array = {label_loginname,
    loginname,                       
    label_password,                       
    password,                       
    rememberCB};
    Object[] options = {"Login", "Cancel"};
    int res = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
                                            array,
                                            "Login",
                                            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                                            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                                            null,     //do not use a custom Icon
                                            options,  //the titles of buttons
                                            options[0]); //default button title

    // User hit Login    
    if (res == 0) 
        { 
            System.out.println( "Login" ); 
        }    
    // User hit CANCEL    
    if (res == 1) 
        { 
            System.out.println( "Canceled" ); 
        }    
    // User closed the window without hitting any button    
    if (res == JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION) 
        { 
            System.out.println( "CLOSED_OPTION" ); 
        }


    // Output data in "login" field, if any    
    String newloginname = loginname.getText();    
    String newpassword = new String(password.getPassword());    
    if (newloginname.equalsIgnoreCase("Cody_Coulter") && newpassword.equals("cheche1"))
        {
            System.out.println("Login Successful!");
            boolean selectedCB = rememberCB.isSelected();    
            System.out.println( "selectedCB: " + selectedCB );
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            Object[] array1= {"It's about time to choose"};
            Object[] options1= {"Leave", "Keep Going"};
            int res1 = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
                                            array1,
                                            "There",
                                            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                                            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                                            null,     //do not use a custom Icon
                                            options1,  //the titles of buttons
                                            options1[0]); //default button title
            if(res1==1)
                {
                    String name1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                                                        "What is your name?");
                    int length = 0;
                    length = newpassword.length();
                    String Pass = "*";
                    newpassword =newpassword.replaceAll(".","*");
                    System.out.println("Username: "+newloginname+"\nPassword: "+
                                        newpassword+"\nName: "+name1);
                }

        }
    else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Wrong Username or Password!");
            isValid=false;
         }
        }
    // Output data in "password" field, if any    
    // Output state of "remember me" check box    

    }

}
```

This is just the login screen for the program, but I just want to be able to:

- Edit the user or password by choice, such as enter old pass: now new: repeat: and saving the new password.
- Create a file dump only accessed through this program containing basic files such as docx, pptx, etc
- How to edit the Username, password, or add new users to the program, only by having an admin password.
- If I have the only account to this program and someone else wants one, the lines reading would be:

  ```
  Username: _____
  Password: _____
  Retype Password:_____
  Authentication: _____
  ```

  and it then creates a permament account.

Sorry for the unorthodox questions, but I am extremely curious, as well as new to these boards. I just want to know if it's possible with java, and if so, where I could reference the material to learn/teach myself.

Comment: Yes, you can do all of these things. Making a standalone Java application is easy, just exporting as JAR. Other stuff is a bit more complicated, and what you describe is far more advanced than your question title. If you haven't worked with basic file IO I'd say it's unrealistic at this point.

Comment: It is certainly possible to re-implement TrueCrypt from the ground-up in java, but teaching how to do it is a rather big task for an SO question....!  Perhaps you could break down specific questions you have about specific tasks you are having trouble accomplishing and ask questions that are easy to give a correct technical answer to?

Comment: Thank you for your input. Sorry it was so much to ask, just not accustomed to these forums yet and wording with them. But thank y'all very much, I will definitely take this into effect next time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but there are too many things to answer in one post I think.

What you should look into is the Scanner class in the Java Core Library. With the Scanner class you can read from and to file. Search here for some tips. With Scanner you can thus have a file with the password written (keep the file protected), and you can change the password by rewriting the password on the file (and reading from the same file).

Comment: He not just wants to read/write text files, but make a wrapper for other files (with encryption and file associations and such), so `Scanner` isn't exactly the best choice. Maybe `DataOutputStream` would be more suitable. Also, *WRITING A PASSWORD TO A FILE?* Are you crazy? At the very least, hash the password and write that.

Comment: Of course, this only works to stop users from accessing the file through the program. There's nothing to stop someone from actually opening the file itself.

Comment: You can write it to a file using some kind of encryption?

Comment: The idea came from an app that's circulating around the app store: A photo vault. It stores photos in that cache, not accessible in the photo viewer... of course that's a mobile device based on apps alone, but is there a similar way with PC? Such as having the files hidden to the point it's almost impossible to find, and the quickest way is through this program. If there's any way to do so at least. And to Zong Zheng Li, not necessarily to the file directly, but to a directory that contains the files, that can only be accessed through such directory. Such as previously mentioned.